# How to launch babun in a specified directory via the command line

Tags: bash, shell, visual-studio-code, command-line-arguments, babun

now I'm currently using Visual Studio Code and I wanted to make the terminal use babun instead of the default `cmd.exe`
In fact, I have already managed to do that in theory - the problem is that, unlike with `cmd.exe`, the directory that I'm in upon starting the terminal is no longer the currently open project, it's just simply `/home/myusername` (i.e. a path in babun's directory tree).
This kinda sucks, since I don't really want to navigate to my directory every time.
Next, I also found out how to tell babun (in my case, `zsh.exe`) to use a default directory such as `C:/` by adding `cd /cygdrive/c` to the end of .zshrc - Unfortunately, that's not what I want either, since I don't want babun to **always** use the same directory.

Now I figured that, seeing as this would be the most comfortable option with VSC*, there might be some console argument that tells `zsh.exe` to use a specific directory. Sadly, I couldn't find anything, hence this question.
Weirdly enough

Anyone know how to help me out? Appreciate the help :)

*VSC allows you to specify the path to your shell, as well as an array of arguments that will be passed.

Comment: If I wanted to do the same thing with cmd.exe, I'd do  
`cmd.exe /k "cd C:\desired\path"`  
Unfortunately, that doesn't work with babun :(

Comment: Is it possible to add a check to your .zshrc whether the caller was vscode? Another idea could be to write a cmd file that changes to the right dir then invokes zsh.exe. I have neither of these tools installed except cygwin, just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You could place your directory into a cmd file and run it as a shell:

```
d:
@rem note that's important to change the drive 'permanently'
cd d:\home
zsh.exe
```

And then specify this cmd file as shell to invoke.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, but seeing as I'd like the terminal to run inside of VSC, I'm not sure it'll work

Comment: @PixelMaster Did you have a look into this: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15531 ? `terminalHere.create`

Comment: Haven't had a look so far, but I don't think it'd help - seeing as I don't want the regular windows shell, but a babun shell.

The normal cmd.exe-shell works fine & launches in the correct directory.

Anyways, I opened an issue on babun's github repository. Hopefully someone there will know an answer (and also make the effort of sharing it ^^)

Answer (score 0):

Open the desired directory in a file explorer, `right click`, then select `Open Babun here`.

Comment: I know that this works, I even reference this possibility in the question. The goal here is to open babun via the command line, not manually with a mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Babun currently does not natively support a command line parameter specifying the directory to launch in.

However, there is a [pull request in the Babun GitHub](https://github.com/babun/babun/pull/398) which solves the issue. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be likely to be accepted anytime soon, though.

To gain access to the feature manually, check out the pull request.